# Java sdk Hyperledger v1.0

Tags: java, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

i started working in hyperledger Java SDK i followed their README.md and i built the network for their test case, but when i'm running the test i got many errors caused by

> could not find"/home/haikal/test.properties"

(even if she exists),

so i really don't know from where to start using sdk java and i can't find any docs for the v1.0,

could someone help me to how start using sdk java and some steps or docs that may help me please?

thank you

Comment: till now, no official document for the sdk. The only way is to review the source code or take the End2endIT.java( IF you want to deploy the chaincode by SDK) or End2endAndBackAgainIT.java (IF you already deployed the chaincode by cli )  for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I'm trying to run those unit test it got could not find test.properties do you an idea how to fix it ?

Comment: can you provide more error information?

Comment: could not find test.properties   (that's it)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I met the same problem, there is no doc for java sdk now, what we can do is read the source code of the sdk , if you want to find out what is the problem, I suggest you to add the log in the source code to help you to do the troubleshooting.

Comment: yup, thats what i did and some function works other no (or maybe it's because my problem) ,thank you